# Android application with android directory/package

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-source

I have seen some android application with a directory named as "android" which contains framework files.

Can anyone tell me about he implementation procedure and how it is achieved?

Answer (score 0):

To access framework APIs or symbols which are not enabled in the public SDK, you can utilise those APIs by compiling the framework or services jar from AOSP and add it as a library module to the AndroidStudio project or just directly add to the project with the dependency for the jar via compileOnly files in app's build.gradle.